# How to start the XAMPP control panel on Fedora 27?

Tags: linux, fedora, python, xampp

I downloaded xampp from the official site. I followed [this](https://www.abouthack.com/2015/04/installing-xampp-control-panel-on-linux) and [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/554535/801246). Then I had to download pygtk2 and pygtk2-libglade. But after trying to run this line:

```
sudo python /opt/lampp/share/xampp-control-panel/xampp-control-panel.py
```

I get [this](https://notepad.pw/s9a7yv1n).

What am I missing? What to do?

Answer (score 0):

If You want to run Xampp ON any Linux Distro Just do the Following

```
cd /opt/lampp && sudo ./xampp start
```

and then open your browser and type localhost to chech if your local server is up and running

Comment: Yeah that works fine. But I want to start the Control Panel.

Answer (score 0):

To Start The Control Panel run

```
cd /opt/lampp && sudo ./manager-linux-x64.run
```